How to control .Net extension host (async) dispose order?
In short I registered a HttpClient and a bunch of services that inject it in the regular constructor way, and it works perfectly.
However one service has a DisposeAsync method that requires sending an http call to clean up an id in a web service, which means that it needs a valid HttpClient instance. Since it's async, the sync HttpClient.Dispose is called and finished by the time I can use it, so it throws an object disposed exception.
Is there a way to sequence things so that the HttpClient is disposed last? I'm obviously open to a custom built wrapper around it, I just couldn't see how it would help in this case.

The framework should dispose of injected services always after the consuming services are disposed of. If this is not happening, you might have a special use case. Can you demonstrate this issue with a MRE?

Can you provide a reference for that claim? That is not what I've noticed in .Net 8 and Extension Host 8.0.0. If you're right then the next step is a bug report, but I'd like to see where you got that from.

You can see this behavior in the source code, but all DI Containers that I know of behave this way, because not following this practice is a design flaw: if a dependency would be disposed before its consumer is, it means that the consumer can't use the dependency from inside its dispose method. Not disposing in opposite order of creation is a design flaw for DI Containers within the .NET platform.

Damn, user error as usual. Thanks for confirming that it's supposed to work, it lead me to the fix.

Turns out it was user error, I didn't call Dispose() on my IHost, only StopAsync(). Since StopAsync() calls my stop method in the hosted service I had put the dispose call there so I didn't notice that the full lifecycle of the service setup wasn't running.

No, there is no way to force a specific order.
The solution is to change the architecture so that http call will be made just before dispose of the service provider.
In short: don't make a call in DisposeAsync, do it before dispose.

Or don't dispose of the HttpClient, that would be even cleaner, it would let me put the dispose code in DisposeAsync where it belongs. However, I didn't ask for alternatives, I'm more interested in an idiomatic fix.

HttpClient have to be disposed. Every disposable thing have to be disposed. The real problem here is that you're trying to do important business thing in a method that is not supposed to do that. It's just a bad idea.

Not really, the finalizer will shut down the socket when the application exits, which is after any awaitable calls that use it are finished. Also I won't argue with you why I'm trying to put code to shut down my application in the (async) function that gets called when the service in charge of it is getting shut down.

Since .NET Core you don't have any guarantee that finalizer will be called at all. It's because finalizers might not be called at application termination. There was that guarantee in old .NET Framework, but now there's none.
